# Jquery Ajaxform with input type=file and multifile

Tags: jquery, ajaxform

Im using ajax form with multifile.

However ajaxform just seems to quietly die and does not do anything if using multifile.

Multifile is just a jquery plugin that builds a list of input type=file so that you can upload multiple files at once, before which you can add/delete your file upload list.

I've looked at multifile and made one change to ensure that it generated a unique name as well as id which it didn't do before and i've checked the form elements multifile is building which all appear to be correct. From looking at ajaxform, it seems that it shoulld just generate the iframe as normal and post the multiple input type=file but it does nothing.

Has anyone else experienced problems with multiple input type=file uploads

Answer (score 0):

I'll take a look. The demo looks good.

After looking at multifile, i found that it was intercepting submit, ajaxform and a few other calls to try to disable empty elements from being posted. In doing so (at least for ajaxfor)m, it was corrupting the options and instance id for Ajaxform. As ajaxform does not post empty elements anyway, the method in multifile was redudant, so i removed it. There is still some odd things going on with multifile when trying to remove added files from the queue (first file only) and i cannot see that it is related to my intercept change in multifile. I think there is another conflict going on and events are not bound correctly resulting in that odd behaviour.

Anyway i'm going to try uploadify which is prettier for sure and hopefully more functional. Thanks for the heads up.